# (How) can I create a selector function with a type parameter as a variable?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-5

The methods [System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby), *.OrderByDescending*, *.ThenBy*, and *.ThenByDescending* have a parameter "keySelector" with two type parameters: TSource and TKey.

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector);
```

I would like to create the *keySelector* parameter beforehand and then pass it on to the aforementioned four methods.

Imagine I have an entity class *MyEntity* with three properties, e.g. a string, an integer and a boolean (and some entity types that inherit *MyEntity*). I would like to create the *keySelector* parameter for the sorting methods through another method.

```
private static Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> GetExpression<TSource, TKey>(string propertyName) where TSource : MyEntity
{
    return propertyName switch
    {
        "propa" => entity => entity.MyPropertyA,
        "propb" => entity => entity.MyPropertyB,
        "propc" => entity => entity.MyPropertyC,
        _ => throw new Exception("Unknown property: " + propertyName)
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting two errors:

- [CS0029](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0029) - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'TKey'
- [CS1662](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1662) - Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

CS1662 can be resolved by returning `entity => (TKey)entity.MyPropertyA`, but then CS0029 logically remains.

Is there any way to build the *keySelector* parameter in advance? Because currently I am forced to repeat that switch expression four times. (And there are actually nine properties.)

Comment: To *call* `GetExpression`, you'd need to know (at your compile time) what the type of `TKey` is. So the only way to do that when it might be different is to be inside *some other method* that's generic in `TKey` and `TSource`, and at that point, it may as well just be passed a `Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>` itself. Why is the property to sort by being passed around as a *string* rather than the `keySelector` already?

Comment: In the front-end the user can click on a table column header to have the list sorted by that property. Therefore the front-end sends a string to an API end-point (and a boolean called "ascending"), which indicates the property on which the entity query needs to be sorted.

Comment: Think about the return type of e.g. `OrderBy`. Remember that generic type parameters (e.g. `TKey`) are statically computed at compile time. If you use or assign the result of calling `OrderBy` then it must have a static, non-generic type. What type would that be when you don't know the return type from `GetExpression`? Will you be calling a method after the sorting that throws away / doesn't need the `TKey` parameter e.g. a `Select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the problem from a different angle because what's asked for in the title of the question isn't really doable:

> Is there any way to build the keySelector parameter in advance? Because currently I am forced to repeat that switch expression four times. (And there are actually nine properties.)

You can reduce the repetition by a) Applying a silly `OrderBy` expression first so that you're always working with a `IOrderedQueryable<T>` and b) Supply your own extension methods that decides which `ThenXxx` method to chain based on a boolean parameter<sup>1</sup>:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> ThenBy<TSource, TKey>(
                      this IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source,
                      Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector,
                      bool descending = false)
{
    if(descending) return source.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
    return source.ThenBy(keySelector);
}
```

Then in your calling code, you have

```
var myUnorderedQuery = ...
var mySortedQuery = myUnsortedQuery.OrderBy(x=>1);
foreach(<sort item to apply>)
{
    bool descending = <logic>
    switch (propertyName)
    {
        case "propa":
            mySortedQuery = mySortedQuery.ThenBy(entity=>entity.PropertyA, descending);
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

And you only have that `switch` appearing once in your code now.

---

If this was `IEnumerable<T>` instead, it would be even easier since the moral equivalent of the above extension method is built-in as [`CreatedOrderedEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iorderedenumerable-1.createorderedenumerable?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_IOrderedEnumerable_1_CreateOrderedEnumerable__1_System_Func__0___0__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___0__System_Boolean_), albeit in that case you have to supply a comparer or know to default that to `Comparer<T>.Default`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The alternative is an `OrderBy` extension method that accepts `IQueryable<T>`, checks whether it's in fact `IOrderedQueryable<T>` and uses that to select whether it uses `OrderBy` or `ThenBy` on it. But I find that approach a bit more "magic" and a pain if you want to override the order of something that turns out already to be `IOrderedQueryable<T>`.

Comment: That works, thank you! I actually used the 'magic' alternative, because there won't come any other places in the API controller where ordering happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `object` as the common key type (SQL Translation will not use the type for sorting) and specify the `TSource` type explicitly, you can do:

```
public static Expression<Func<MyEntity, Object>> GetExpression(string propName) {
    switch (propName) {
        case "propa":
            return (MyEntity s) => s.MyPropertyA;

        case "propb":
            return (MyEntity s) => s.MyPropertyB;

        case "propc":
            return (MyEntity s) => s.MyPropertyC;

        default:
            throw new Exception($"Unrecognized property: {propName}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Would work if I could specify TSource explicitly. However, we use different views, which are mapped to different entity types, and I'd like to use the same method to sort all of them based on the columns they have in common. That's why I used "where T : MyEntity".

Comment: Actually this works as well! TSource does not need to be specified explicitly. The trick was to use "object" instead of TKey:
private static Expression<Func<TSource, object>> GetExpression<TSource>(string propertyName) where TSource : MyEntity { ... }